# Resize images right after download in NodeJS, using request and gm modules

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, node-async, node-request

I'm trying to resize images right after I've downloaded them using nodejs, request and gm modules but I'm having a hard time understading to pipe stuff properly.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');
var folderImages = './images/';

var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {

    // Renaming the images
    var thumb350 = task.target.replace('.jpg', '-350.jpg');

    // The target path/images
    var target350 = path.join(folderImages, thumb350);

    // Download the images
    request
        .get(task.PhotoURL)
        .on('response', function(response) {
            console.log(task.PhotoURL + ' : ' + response.statusCode, response.headers['content-type']);
            callback();
        })
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(task.target));

    // How can I run this function on files that get downloaded?
    var resizePhotos = gm(task.target)
        .resize('350')
        .write(target350, function (err) {
            if (!err){
                console.log(task.target, ': 350 done');
            }
            else {
                console.log(task.target, ': error');
            }
        });

}, 50);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen the `finish` event on the writeStream and then put resizing logic in the callback:

```
...
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(task.target))
.on('finish', function(){ 
    //called when writing to disk is complete
    var resizePhotos = gm(task.target)
        .resize('350')
        .write(target350, function (err) {
            if (!err){
                console.log(task.target, ': 350 done');
            }
            else {
                console.log(task.target, ': error');
            }
        });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `request.get` returns a stream, and you can just `gm(request.get(url)).resize(350)` instead of writing to filesystem and load it out again.